# Why does this circuit work?

Tags: transistors

I'm suffering from a bit of confusion here and I was hoping that some kind soul here would be able to help me out. I want to build a small DC motor circuit just for fun, but I can't understand some aspects of the circuit (shown in the picture below)

[image: Copied from the guide I'm using at http://learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/Vibration-motor-circuit.php].

So basically I understand that Ic = Beta * Ib. Thus (assuming that D3 is 3.3 V and Beta is around 100), I can say that Ic = 100*(3.3/1000) = 0.33 Amps.

Then, in order to find the voltage available to the motor, I must find the voltage drop across the 33 Ohm resistor and subtract that from my power rail voltage (5 V).

So 5V - (0.33)(33)  =  5V - 10.89V

Which is quite clearly ludicrous. Can anybody quickly explain to me the fault in my reasoning? I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: You should consider the VBE, VCE and VBE voltages of the transistor. To do so you should have a basic understanding in transistors and 2N2222 datasheets.

Comment: Please find the DC resistance of the Motor. A simple Ohmmeter will do.

Comment: `So 5V - (0.33)(33) = 5V - 10.89V` this got me as a newbie as well. 0.33A is only the *maximum* current that can flow through the transistor.  In your circuit the maximum current will be certainly not exceeding 0.15A (5V/33Ohms ≈ 0.15A).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... I can say that Ic = 100*(3.3/1000) = 0.33 Amps.

Incorrect. You can say that Ic has a *maximum* of 0.33A (or whatever it would *actually* be with the correct values and formulae). If the supply isn't actually capable of supplying that much for any reason then the transistor is [operating in **saturation** mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_junction_transistor#Regions_of_operation), where it acts as a switch. Which is exactly what we want it doing for operating a motor.

Comment: From your rough estimate, If D3 = 3.3V, and it's entirety was across the 1K Resistor, then 0V would be across Vbe. So that transistor would be in cut-off, not saturation. A better estimation of a **maximum** is to guess that Vbe should be 0.7V and then Ic = 100((3.3V-0.7V)/1000) = 0.26A

Comment: @Dave: It's not my rough estimate, and I doubt the full 3.3V would be dropped across the resistor, only 2.6V.

Comment: Could you please elaborate as to why we want the transistor operating as a switch in this circuit, or indeed in any circuit where we operate a motor?

Comment: @AndreBododea: Vce is lowest in saturation, which means 1) maximum power is delivered to the load, and 2) minimum power is dissipated by the transistor.

Answer (score 0):

You can pretty much be guaranteed that your \$I_C\$ current is going to be

$$I_C\leq\frac{5V}{33\Omega+R_{motor}}\leq\frac{5V}{33\Omega}=152mA$$

Just because there's no way for it to be higher than that, no matter what you do with the transistor!

From there you can consider your base current, \$I_B\$, and its effect on the collector current.

Since the \$V_{BE(sat)}\$ is 0.7V typically, we can try

$$I_C=\beta\times \frac{3.3V-V_{BE(sat)}}{R_B}=100\times\frac{3.3V-0.7}{1k\Omega}=260mA$$

It's safe to assume (as @Ignacio pointed out) the transistor is in saturation (because \$I_C<260mA\$), and the actual \$I_C\$ is less than 152mA due to the resistance hanging off the collector.

Comment: Quick question then: why do we even bother with the transistor at all? If the current is limited at 152 mA, and the transistor sets Ic to a maximum but unachievable currents of 260 mA, then couldn't we just leave it out altogether?

Comment: @AndreBododea: Of course you can. But then how would the MCU control the motor?

Comment: Sorry, but you cannot assume the transistor is in saturation. This would typically assume a $/beta$ in the range of 10 to 20, for a current range of 26 to 52 mA.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast It's been a LONG time, but when your theoretical saturation current is much greater than your possible Ic current, doesn't that imply saturation? Or are you saying that the ACTUAL \$\beta\$ could be anything from 20-200?

Comment: @Daniel - Nope. Sorry. Saturation is defined as a condition of Vce < Vbe. And if "saturation current" (where? collector-emitter? base-emitter?) is base current, and greater than collector current, you'll burn out the base. If "saturation current" is greater than "possible Ic current" then it can't possibly be collector current, so I'm not sure just what you meant. In any event, saturation usually takes place at low $\beta$, and designers typically use a collector/base ratio of 10 to 20 to ensure saturation.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast ok, more technically, if \$I_B\times\beta=I_C(sat)>I_C\$ the transistor is in saturation... If this were not the case, how would the transistor ever go into active mode where the transistor is controlling the current (ie \$I_C=I_B\times\beta\$)

Comment: @Daniel - In general, increasing Ib always increases Ic, so the transistor is _always_ controlling the current. And Ic = Ib x beta is the definition of beta. So, I am at a loss as to what you think is going on. What you say does not seem to make sense.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Ignacio reached the same conclusion. Is there something wrong with his answer as well?

Comment: @Daniel - No, Ignacio was entirely correct, but you have taken his answer and distorted the underlying effects. At the very least, you seem to be unaware that $\beta$ varies wildly with both collector current and collector/emitter voltage. And a $\beta$ of 100 is simply not likely for a transistor in saturation.

Answer (score 0):

[Horowitz and Hill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Electronics) explain this memorably by means of a cartoon 'Transistor Man' who sits inside the transistor constantly watching \$I_B\$ on an ammeter and trying to keep \$I_C\$ equal to \$\beta \times I_B\$. **But** the only control he has at his disposal is a variable resistance connected between C and E. If he turns the variable resistance all the way down to zero and the collector current is still less than that, well, that's all he can do.

In reality his variable resistance doesn't quite go to zero - and it isn't actually a resistance - which is why checking the transistor's datasheet for the collector-emitter saturation voltage, \$V_{CEsat}\$, is always a good idea, and why you sometimes need to give a transistor more base current than the simple \$I_C = \beta \times I_B\$ equation suggests.